# document.getElementById("foo").innerHTML does print HTML but isn't visible

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using this iteration in JavaScript to generate some >li< tags.

```
for ( var i = 0, l = response.items.length; i < l; i++ ) 
{
    //alert(response.items[i].id.videoId);
    document.getElementById("thumbs").innerHTML += "<li class='item-thumbs span3 hardstyle'>Shortened for this question</li>";
}
```

As you can see in the picture below, the >li< tags are being generated but the screen stays "white".

[image: Screenshot]

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? This script is sitting at the bottom of the code, maybe that's why I can't see any elements, because the rest of the page is being generated before I iterate through this object?

Thank you in advance,
Stephan

Comment: Try to set the `z-index` of the `ul` higher than that of the element at that place

Comment: looks like you have CSS issue

Comment: Thanks but tried that already. I've added those elements manually and they actually show, it's exactly the same code generated by the iteration.

Comment: Do you have a live code example. It looks like you probably have some other styles that are making it not visible. Are there videos in the LI tags? how are they being loaded in since your image has the word `Videos` or some bootstrap css conflict?

Comment: Question has been solved. Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should try to remove

- **height:0px;**
- **overflow:hidden;**

css values from #thumbs element (at least second one!)

```
    #thumbs {height:0px; overflow:hidden;}
```

compare here: https://jsfiddle.net/vtrpyqdL/ (try to run this one then remove css section)

Comment: As you can see in the screenshot, the height/width of the element is 270x202.

Comment: That's not the #thumbs itself, rather its parent. Other than that, probably the right answer.

Comment: it rather about overflow:hidden than height

Comment: Thank you for your comment. This was actually the whole problem! I do not understand though. I added them manually and they actually show..

Comment: Did you add them manually to the same ul that was in the same section?